# How to tell Eclipse where to put automatically generated methods?

Tags: java, eclipse

I like to use Eclipse's automatically generated methods feature when writing method calls, where I just hover under the unknown (because it hasn't been written yet) method name and have Eclipse create it with the specified parameters. Also, I like my new methods to go at the bottom of my code so that I can read it in a more linear fashion.

But whenever I generate a new method this way, Eclipse puts it directly under the method I am typing from, and any other existing methods get pushed down.

How do I change the settings to put the new automatically generated methods at the bottom of the code?

Comment: Good question, but I don't think this is possible.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Oh well.